# Convert method won't work when I'm trying to convert string variables to numeric & DateTime types (Npgsql Parameters)

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

So, I am using C#/.NET and am using Npgsql.  Basically, I keep running into the error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type NumericHandler'` and I can't seem to resolve it.

The error seems pretty self-explanatory.  Basically, I'm trying to use a string but Postgresql wants a Numeric data type. (Would that be a decimal or double data type?)

For some context, I am re-writing old VB code to C# and in the VB version the initial declarations of the numeric variables are strings.  And in the code there is some string manipulation methods that are used.

My thought process was it'd be easier and faster to just let the string manipulation stuff happen and then convert it to a decimal or a double later on. (Decimal's and Double's are Numeric postgresql equivalents, I think?)

So here's an example of the initial declartions:

```
string tno = "";
string iw = "";
string ws = "";
string ftg = "0";
string hl = "0";
string ll = "0";
string date = "2012/02/04";
string va = "0";
string dev = "0";
```

Later on in the code there are some string manipulation methods that are used.  As I said earlier I thought it'd be faster to just use some Conversion methods to convert the strings to their proper data types before feeding it to postgresql.

For example:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(tno);
```

Here's an example of the SQL string:

```
string sqlString = @"UPDATE header
SET ft = @gftg, high_limit=@ghl, low_limit=@gll, start_date = @gsdd, avg_ga = @gvgga, std_dev = @gstd
WHERE cmpy_id = 'ABC' and tag_no = @gto and ip_num = @gim";
```

Here's the Npgsql parameter code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gim", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = iw;                              
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gftg", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ftg;                            
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ghl", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = hl;                              
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gll", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ll;                              
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gsdd", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = date;                             
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gvgga", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = va;                              
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gstd", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = dev;
```

This isn't really working though and it's probably for an obvious reason that I'm hoping you guys can help me with.

Is there no easy way to do this and will I just have to change the initial variable declarations to the correct data types right away?  So for example perhaps It should be more like this?  Then I would have to mess with the code below it and do some string manipulation equivalents or something like that..

```
decimal tno = "";
string iw = "";
string ws = "";
decimal ftg = "0";
decimal hl = "0";
decimal ll = "0";
string date = "2012/02/04";
decimal va = "0";
decimal dev = "0";
```

Any ideas why the `Convert.ToDecimal(tno)` before inputting into the postgres npgsql parameters isn't working?

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you appear to be using the result of `Convert.ToDecimal(tno)`, though it's notable that `Convert.ToDecimal("")` would fail in any case. The parameter values would be expecting properly typed values, since it's up to the driver to provide conversions, and typically those are limited to types that match (so for a `Date` parameter it likely wants a `DateTime` instance and not a string). I would not use `Convert` in any instance where the types are known; use predictable, recoverable approaches like `decimal.TryParse` and `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert To clarify, later on in the code, the empty strings are filled with values that would work as decimals.  So you'd recommend I try `decimal.TryParse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` instead?  Why is that?  And why is `Convert.ToDecimal()` not working if I input values that would work as decimals?

Comment: Using `Decimal.TryParse` with different variables fixed this.  Thanks so much! @JeroenMostert

Comment: I can't tell why your code as a whole isn't working, since we don't have the code as a whole. I only observed that `Convert.ToDecimal("")` will not work (i.e. invoking it on the empty string). The error you're getting is not related to any `Convert` call, since that's the result of the Npgsql driver choking on the parameter value, regardless of how that value is established, and the message specifically talks about not being able to convert a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jeroen Mostert I finally fixed this..  It was simply that `Convert.ToDecimal()` didn't work.  So I just used `Decimal.TryParse()` instead with a new variable and it works now..  (Now onto my other errors)

Here's an example:

```
decimal ftgAsDecimal;
Decimal.TryParse(ftg, out ftgAsDecimal);
```

I fed it into my Npgsql parameters like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gftg", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ftgAsDecimal;
```

For DateTime variables I had to use `DateTime.ParseExact()` like Jeroen recommended above.  Here's an example:

```
DateTime dateAsDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM-dd-yyyy", null);
```

(Keep in mind `date` above is a DateTime data typed variable)

Just for absolute clarity purposes this is what it looked like being fed to Npgsql parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gsdd", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = dateAsDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.html

It looks like there's a type for Double:  `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that.  My suspicion is that Npgsql doesn't like that the variables input into the SQL parameters in the SQL string are strings.  I think since the previous version was in VB that it's much more forgiving with data types and does automatic type coercion and whatnot.  I'm wondering if I just need to declare the intial variables as decimals or doubles or whaterver.

Comment: Yes, I would think you should use the actual data types in C# for the respective db types

Comment: I agree, I'm just trying to find an easier way as the old VB code uses some string manipulation that I'd rather avoid having to re-write.  Why wouldn't `Convert.ToDecimal()` work if I input values that would work as decimals?  I'm confused on this.

Comment: My advice is to follow the guidance in @jeroen-mostert's comment above and use `Decimal.TryParse` or some variant of that since you would be able to guarantee type safety with that method

Comment: Yep, I followed Jeroen's advice and it worked flawlessly.  What a legend.  (I answered my own question with Jeroen's advice)